# PHP Session Keep Alive

Tags: php, session, timeout, keep-alive

Once my users login, i create a PHP session for them and store the user id in the session. But sometimes the user's session times-out and the time is not really predictable as it happens at different times. A user is sometimes doing something on the site which takes time before they press save at this point the session times out.

I have a jQuery keepAlive function that calls a file name keepAlive.php every x amount of seconds. But not sure what code to put in the php file to keeep the php session alive. Any ideas? Should i just do start_session() and thats it?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah and define your $_SESSION hyper global as itself. - $_SESSION = $_SESSION;

Comment: Are you sure that session_start() is called at the top of every page? (first line)

Answer (score 1):

The lack of the predictability has to do with your garbage collection settings (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php for the long description). But the killing of old sessions happens by a random chance that then kills every session older than a certain time.

to start the session all you need is start_session()

but if you need things to last longer then you should probably change your php.ini to extend how long it starts before they get killed. (session.gc_maxlifetime)

Comment: +1: but a couple of caveats - the session timestamp (in the default handler) is updated when the session is closed - hence with only a session_start the code must end cleanly. Also it is *possible* to configure the session cookie lifetime to be less the rather erroneously named gc_maxlifetime making the session inaccessible.